# Infinity scroll with RTKQuery

Tags: infinite-scroll, rtk-query

I am trying to implement infinity scroll using RTKQuery. I almost do it but face with cache behavior problem. When component with request rendering first time, scroll works fine, but if i move to another page, and after that return back, page parametr reset to 1(because of useState), and data from response which already exist inside rtk cache, merges to current cache. That causes problem with keys etc. I tried to implement custom function for serializeQueryArgs, but i probably not fully understand how it works, cause after that endpoint cache started clean itself during each req. How can i clean endpoint cache after unmounting component?

Endpoint implementation:

```
fetchUsers: build.query<UsersResponse, QueryParams>({
        query: params => ({ url: generateGetUsersUrl(params.page, params.size) }),
        serializeQueryArgs: ({ endpointName }) => {
          return endpointName
        },
        merge: (currentCache, newCache) => {
          currentCache.users.push(...newCache.users)
        },
        forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
          return currentArg?.page !== previousArg?.page
        },
        providesTags: res =>
          res?.users ? [...res.users.map(user => ({ type: "User" as const, id: user.id })), "Role"] : ["User", "Role"],
        transformResponse: (data: UsersDataFromBackend, meta) => ({
          users: usersTransformer(data),
          totalCount: Number(meta?.response?.headers.get("X-Total-Count"))
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. QueryParams can be used inside merge method:

```
fetchUsers: build.query<UsersResponse, QueryParams>({
        query: params => ({ url: generateGetUsersUrl(params.page, params.size) }),
        serializeQueryArgs: ({ endpointName }) => {
          return endpointName
        },
        merge: (currentCache, newCache, {args}) => {
          if(args.page === 1) currentCache.users = []
          currentCache.users.push(...newCache.users)
        },
        forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
          return currentArg?.page !== previousArg?.page
        },
        providesTags: res =>
          res?.users ? [...res.users.map(user => ({ type: "User" as const, id: user.id })), "Role"] : ["User", "Role"],
        transformResponse: (data: UsersDataFromBackend, meta) => ({
          users: usersTransformer(data),
          totalCount: Number(meta?.response?.headers.get("X-Total-Count"))
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save page to redux store instead of saving useState(),

when click   `next()`

function also chage page in store

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).